# How to find max value in a table but with different range?

Tags: excel, vba

Supposingly I have this table that I have pulled from the database:

```
Item number | Part number | Lead Time
   001      |     002     |   1.00
   001      |     005     |   5.00
   001      |     079     |   15.00
   002      |     078     |   10.00
   002      |     079     |   15.00
   003      |     004     |   30.00
   003      |     789     |   45.00
```

Are there any ways that I can add another column to find that maximum lead time of an item number?
E.g:

```
Item number | Part number | Lead Time | Max Lead Time
   001      |     002     |   1.00    |     15.00
   001      |     005     |   5.00    |     15.00
   001      |     079     |   15.00   |     15.00
   002      |     078     |   10.00   |     10.00
   002      |     068     |   3.00    |     10.00
   003      |     004     |   30.00   |     45.00
   003      |     789     |   45.00   |     45.00
```

Comment: a pivot table can do this

Comment: Hi Warcupine, how would you do it in pivot table?

Comment: item number as row max of lead time as value.

Comment: I believe `MAXIFS()` should also work for this

Comment: Thank you @Michael. It worked but since my actual reports have over 100000 rows it takes a while to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use `=MAXIFS()` to do this. That's a `Max()` function that is conditional. The condition here is that Column `A` values considered for the `Max()` match the current row's column `A` value:

```
=MAXIFS($C$2:$C$8, $A$2:$A$8, A2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @JNevill. I tried this before but forgot to add the ```$``` and ran out of memeory. This formula saved me!